# What's the best way of saying "carry something with you”?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, confusable

Is it okay to ask

> "Why do you always carry with you your laptop or something else…?"

Or is there a more common way of saying that?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why are you using "smth" instead of a whole word?  Why are you using a "..."?  Is that intended to be part of the quote?

Comment: Don't use dictionary's abbreviation such as "sth", "smth" or "esp" because no one *speaks* like that.

Comment: Are you meaning to literally say the words "or something else..." out loud? Or do you mean to refer to a laptop *or some other object*? In that case you should use square brackets, like so: "Why do you always carry with you your laptop [or some other object]?"

Answer (score 1):

Your title is more natural than the quote in the body of your question.

It is more idiomatic to say "carry [object] with you" than to say "carry with you [object]." The second version is not, strictly speaking, incorrect, but no one talks like that. The place I could see that arrangement working is in a poem or song, either to make the meter work out properly or to put special emphasis on the object. In ordinary usage you would have to verbally stress the object in order to emphasize it, instead of putting it at the end of the phrase.

So you can ask someone

> Why do you always carry your laptop with you?

But even that is still a little awkward. To my ear, the sentence sounds more idiomatic if you insert the adverb **around** after the object:

> Why do you always carry your laptop **around** with you?

Some other verbs you can use besides *carry* are: *cart*, *drag*, *lug*, *tow*, *haul*. Some of these would sound more or less natural depending on what the object is; for example, "tow" is most often used in relation to something with wheels. These verbs all but require "around."

If you do not want to use "around" you can use the verbs **bring** or **take**:

> Why do you always bring [take] your laptop with you?

This has the connotation of there being *a single specific* place that you always bring your laptop, unlike "carry around" which connotes the continuous practice of bringing your laptop everywhere you go. "Bring" is used when the question is asked when you have arrived at the location, and "take" is used when the question is asked as you are leaving to go to the location.